# Using ViewStub within ListViews causes onItemClick problems

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, viewstub

I have an interesting dilemma. I have a `ListView` which I am using to contain `CardView`s. However, each `CardView` is actually a pair of two: one default (front) card, and then a back card that I am animating as a flip upon the user clicking the card. Since the user may not click on any list item, I am using a `ViewStub` as the back card, and will lazy inflate upon the list item click.

So the first time the user clicks a card to flip to the back, everything looks good and the flip works (`onItemClick()` gets called from clicking anywhere within the card). However, any further attempts to flip over to the front again do not trigger the `onItemClick()` call, UNLESS I click the very top of the view (list item).

I've done lots of debugging (changing focusability and sizing) and figured out that this is being caused only after the `ViewStub` inflation. Making both front and back cards normal `CardView`s allows the `onItemClick()` to fire successfully every time.

So what is the reason why the `ViewStub` is fubaring my `onItemClick()`? Is there a way to fix it, rather than have all of my views inflated automatically?

Here is the code I'm using:

**card_container_layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <include layout="@layout/card_front_view"
        android:id="@+id/main_card_view_layout" />

    <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub_flipped_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/flipped_card"
        android:layout="@layout/card_back_view" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**card_front_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_height">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_main_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/my_image"
                android:background="#ff10fffd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                style="@style/main_card_title_text"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:background="#5b000000"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_item_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                style="@style/main_card_text" />

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_sync_state"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**card_back_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/flipped_card"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Here are the items:"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/card_flipped_title_text"
            android:background="#ad000000"/>
        <GridView android:id="@+id/grid_images"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numColumns="3">
            <!-- make believe there were items here -->
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: on which view are you calling setting the click listener to? I'm gonna bet it's `main_card_view_layout` or something inside it.

Comment: I've set the `card_container_layout` as the list item and removed the focus from the child cards, so `onItemClick()` should fire by clicking anywhere in that layout.

Comment: I have same issue...using ViewStub inside ListView with a custom CursorAdapter ...
first time ViewStub inflate ...work fine...
but when scrolling a listview ; call to getView and after BindView  and all ViewStub are changed as if it was one instance of view and id ..?? 
i m debuging this , and i suppose it the same issue as u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did more digging into it and it appears that it's not the `ViewStub` at all causing it, but in fact the `GridView`. For reasons that I was not able to figure out, the `GridView` continued to hijack all touch events, despite setting focusable and clickable to false and blocking descendent focusability as seen in the sample XML above.

Therefore the hacky way I've worked around it, is to intercept all touch events from the GridView, and within the `onTouchListener()`, if I detect a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, indicating that I have been touching the screen and just released, I will then manually perform the same action as I am doing in the rest of the `CardView`.

```
itemGrid.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View grid, MotionEvent event) {
            // hacky way to make sure that we absorb the GridView's focus stealing and still do the right thing
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) doExpectedStuff();
            return true; // absorb the touch here
        }
});
```

Sorry that this isn't the most elegant of solutions, and agree that capturing an up event is not a one-size-fits-all approach for most people, but it helped in my specific situation. Hope that this still may help others.